# jQuery eq to display fade in block

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

What I'm trying to do is to fade in a block which on the CSS is display to none here is what I got:

CSS:

```
.white_content {
    display: none;
    position: relative;;
    width: 5%;
    height: 5%;
    padding: 24px;
    border: 16px solid orange;
    background-color: some;
    z-index:1;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $("#act1").click(function() {
        $('li:eq(0)').fadeIn(400); 
    }); 
    $("#act2").click(function() {
        $('li:eq(1)').fadeIn(400); 
    }); 
});
```

an the HTML:

```
<div id="act1">first click</div> 
<div id="act2">second click</div>  

<ul>
    <li><div id="tos" class="white_content">  
    some text...
    </div></li> 

    <li><div id="tos" class="white_content">   
    other some text
    </div></li> 
</ul>
```

If I change on the jQuery `li:eq(0)` to `#tos` it will work fine but I can't get it to work with `li:eq(0)` since this is what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here. First of all, `id`s must be unique - they cannot repeat as you have done in the code you have here. Secondly, the `display: none` property is set on `div.white_content`, not `li`, so your selector should be `li:eq(n) div.white_content`.

Even then this code should be easily rewritable to something neater, like this:

```
$('div[id^=act]').click(function(){
    var n = parseInt(this.id.substring(3), 10);
    $('li').eq(n-1).find('.white_content').fadeIn(400);
});
```

---

Given your HTML, I think this is what you need:

```
// For the two buttons
$('div[id^=act]').click(function(){
    var n = parseInt(this.id.substring(3), 10);
    $('li').eq(n-1).find('.white_content').fadeToggle(400);
});

// For the close button
$('.close').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.tos').fadeOut(400);
});
```

You're using duplicate `id`s, which is invalid HTML. I've taken the liberty of changing them to classes, which is the correct way to do this. The [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) function looks for the nearest ancestor that matches the selector, in this case the `div` that contains the elements.

On a side note, since `li` are block level elements, you can skip the `div` and put all your contents in the `li` element directly, eliminating one layer of HTML.

Comment: @Yi Jiang i like the neater version one is wat i was looking for but i forgot something how can i close the block, i have an image with an id to close the box on .click the block fadesOut, how can i implement this on the neater code...?

Comment: @don You can use `.toggle` instead of `.click` to do that, or, if you're on version 1.4.4, the `fadeToggle` function will also do

Comment: @Yi Jiang i have try it right now but it didn't work... how would you have done this... this is what i did $(function(){
    
   $("#close").click(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(400); 
    });

Comment: @don Well, it depends on what you actually want. Here's a demo of the jQuery I have, as well as your HMTL and CSS working: http://jsfiddle.net/yijiang/jTmCJ/

Comment: @Yi Jiang well wat im doing is something like a light box the box is way bigger so when i click on lets say an image the image is displayed on the box with some text and to close the box there is an image inside the box to close it...

Comment: @don `$(this).parent().fadeOut` or `$(this).closest(selector).fadeOut()`? `$(this).fadeOut()` will simply cause the close button to disappear.

Comment: @Yi Jiang this is wat i got http://i56.tinypic.com/1214h8y.png but it only closes the the first block even if a first click the second block it only works for the first one not for the second or third etc...

Comment: @Yi Jiang this is wat i did http://i56.tinypic.com/29c28mf.png but it doesn't work on ie...

Comment: @don I can't help you like this. You can probably try editing your question or asking a new one. There's nothing I can do unless I see your HTML

Comment: @Yi Jiang thank's for taking the time on helping me with this problem and again thank you so much... :)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$(function(){
    $("#act1").click(function() {
        $('li:eq(0) div.white_content').fadeIn(400); 
    }); 
    $("#act2").click(function() {
        $('li:eq(1) div.white_content').fadeIn(400); 
    }); 
});
```